# Running tests for my own angular components using guinness, karma, et al

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I'm writing an angular component and I would like to test it the same way the angular.dart project tests their own stuff.  I've largely mimicked the angular.dart setup, and all I'm trying to do at this point is execute a single mock test.  I've gotten karma to launch a Dartium window, but it just sits idle:

[image]

I've looked over my karma config and everything seems right.  You can find the project I'm attempting to test here: https://github.com/bgourlie/varxa-button

Comment: What is your question? If it's the `API keys missing` - this has nothing to do with Karma/Guiness/Angular. This is just Dartium.

Comment: "all I'm trying to do at this point is execute a single mock test. I've gotten karma to launch a Dartium window, but it just sits idle"

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting `autoWatch: true` in the `karma.conf.js` file?

Then whenever you change your tests it should run and output the test results to the console window.